# Windows 8 on HP laptop crashes when waking up from sleep

Tags: windows, windows-8

I always put it to sleep at night, but when I try and turn it on I hit the keyboard to activate it and a Windows screen pops up saying and error has occured. It collects data then reboots and offers to send an error report.

Note this only appears to happen when I'm at home and it's hooked up to 2 monitors and 3-4 USB devices. When it's not connected to everything it looks like sleep actually works.

HP DV7
XG300AV

Comment: upload the collected minidumps (C:\Windows\Minidump). Zip this folder, upload it to your skydrive, dropbox and post a link here.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling display drivers

Firstly, remove old drivers by navigating to device manager, and double-click display adapters, select the driver tab, and select uninstall for your display driver.

Then go download and install the newest display drivers from [HP's website](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-drivers.html)